# Parsing custom php commands in CMS

Tags: php

Ok, so I have searched a lot, with no result. I believe the reason is I don't know what I'm looking for is called.

I'm creating a CMS, and would like to give the tempalte designer / user to enter some php commands in his content.

A simple example would be, if he wants to print he website title, he will have to write:

```
<?php echo $site->title;?>
```

Now, I would like to do this simpler. I have seen it before, but don't know how to find it. Instead of writing the line above, I would like the user to input :
`{site.title}` for example.

A direction to look in, or any kind of hints/suggestions to get me on the right track with this will be very appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: twig ? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: `str_replace`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: How do you suggest using str_replace @PeeHaa ? I thought about it, but it's like I wanna replace these commands on runtime, so run the str_replace function at the beginning to search in the whole file? Doesn't sound efficient. At least if it's written in the html itself. If it's data I'm calling from Database though, it's probably easy to parse it before I print it out,I suppose.

I was thinking if there's something already ready or another approach I havn't thought about. Thank you, will check it out. At least I know now it's called "template engine" that's kinda what I needed

Comment: Well you always have to parse it either way. Either using an external template engine or not. There is no magical way those `{whatever}` codes are going to be changed automatically.